# I see a gap at the bottom of the subview

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder

Basically the second view should go 20px from the top

I see a gap at the bottom of the subview, I can see the bottom of the first view

[Link to screen shot](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/874/bugzk.png)

Is there some way I can set margins or boundaries so the view can go 20px down

Comment: The 20px gap is the same height as the status bar.  Have you tried [___ setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,__,__)]?

Comment: this is what i have put in the code where the animation is being committed and it works but now, the normal view (the one 30px higher is shown) and then it goes 30px down. Where should I put this code for the bounds to be set before the view is shown so the user can't see that the view is moving down
                                          [[settingsViewController view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, -30, 320, 480)];

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to display this view? I don't think we can answer your question without knowing more about how you are showing the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the fix would be

```
-(void)goTo2{

    //calling the .xib file and the SettingsViewController
    SettingsViewController *aSettingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    [self setSettingsViewController:aSettingsView];
    [aSettingsView release];

    [self.window addSubview:[settingsViewController view]];
    //moving the view 30px down
    [[settingsViewController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    //setting the animation
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];  
    [settingsViewController release];
    settingsViewController = nil;
}
```